# Select statement in a form partial for an HABTM association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two models `Client` and `Topic`. Both of which have a HABTM association between them.

I am trying to add a select statement in my `_form` partial in my Client views, that allows the user to add a topic to a client (or edit that topic, etc.).

This is what my form partial looks like:

```
<%= form_for(@client) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :topic %><br />
    <%= f.select :topics, Topic.all.collect { |topic| [topic.name, topic.id] }, {:include_blank => 'None'} %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The first error I got was this:

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in ClientsController#create

Can't mass-assign protected attributes: topics
```

So, in my `Client` model, I added this:

```
attr_accessible :email, :firm_id, :name, :phone, :topics
```

This is the error I now get:

```
NoMethodError in ClientsController#create

undefined method `each' for "1":String
```

The create action of my `Clients` controller is very standard:

```
  def create
    @client = Client.new(params[:client])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @client.save
        format.html { redirect_to @client, notice: 'Client was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @client, status: :created, location: @client }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @client.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

These are the params submitted (notice that `topics` is being passed - instead of `topic_id` but `topic_id` doesn't work either):

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"J172LuZQc5NYoiMSzDD3oY9vGmxxCX0OdxcGm4GSPv8=",
 "client"=>{"name"=>"Jack Daniels",
 "email"=>"jack.daniels@some-email.com",
 "phone"=>"2345540098",
 "firm_id"=>"2",
 "topics"=>"1"},
 "commit"=>"Create Client"}
```

How can I get a topic assigned to my client on the creation of the client with this select statement?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting a "Topic" attribute, Client expects an instance of a Topic class.

Since you are passing IDs, you need to change:

```
<%= f.select :topics, Topic.all.collect { |topic| [topic.name, topic.id] }, {:include_blank => 'None'} %>
```

to set `topic_ids` instead:

```
<%= f.select :topic_ids, Topic.all.collect { |topic| [topic.name, topic.id] }, {:include_blank => 'None'} %>
```

And, of course, in attr_accessible:

```
attr_accessible :email, :firm_id, :name, :phone, :topic_ids
```

Comment: Ahh...of course. Perfect. The Rails Guides are a bit light on these sorts of details, no? Or did I miss it somewhere?

Comment: That part of the guide is definitely not in-your-face:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-association-reference

see "4.3.1.6 collection_singular_ids=ids"

Comment: Yeh...that's pretty obtuse. When I get some time, I will do up some examples and see if they will accept it. Thanks again!